# Awesomium.NET and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, awesomium

I want to create a webservice that takes snapshots of web pages. I chose Awesomium for this mission.
But there is a problem, Awesomium.NET DLL can run only on 32 bit projects, and WCF has to run on any CPU, so obvious it won't run... there is another way to create a web service ( who can run Awesomium.NET )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service has nothing to do with machine it runs on. The hosting process does. In case you host your service under IIS you can explicitly specify if the worker process is 32-bit or 64-bit by using corresponding setting of the application pool.